# Drag and Dropping Multiple Files onto Linux Script

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to drag multiple files onto a shell script and pass those files as positional parameters? In testing this, adding an

`echo "$# $@" > output.txt`

within the script, indicates that only 1 parameter is passed and the parameter that is passed is the last of the files that was chosen before the drag and drop action.

Is there something that can done (trickery or otherwise) to get this action to work?

Comment: Probably depends on the file manager / whatever you're dragging and dropping with. Try to change the redirection to `>> output` to append instead of overwriting the file. Your file manager may be just starting the script once for each file.

Answer (score 1):

The logical thing would be for the window manager to pass the path(s) of the dropped items as arguments to the item onto which they were dropped.

This [tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571) seems to cover bash script arguments fairly well..

> Arguments are accessed inside a script using the variables $1, $2, $3, etc., where $1 refers to the first argument, $2 to the second argument, and so on.

```
echo $1
```

> If you have a variable number of arguments, you can use the "$@" variable, which is an array of all the input parameters. This means you can use a for-loop to iteratively process each one, as illustrated in the following example:

```
for FILE1 in "$@"
do
    wc $FILE1
done
```

Try making a script that outputs all arguments into a text file.  This should help you discover what your window manager is doing.  OR research your window manager to find out how it handles dropping one icon on another.